# Spring + Vault Secret Engine Database Connection

Tags: spring, database, terraform, vault

I've stumbled across a problem with Spring and Vault Secret Engine. I do have a set database connection, for which the lease can be generated succesfully via vault cli (vault read database/creds/my-role)

Now, I do have a spring service deployed via Terraform and a vault policy document:

```
data "vault_policy_document" "this" {
  rule {
    path         = "/database/creds/my-role"
    capabilities = ["read"]
    description  = "Allow service to write and read into/from it's vault database path"
  }
}
```

The service logs:

```
{"type":"application","service":"identcheck-service","timestamp":"2022-02-17 11:54:29,822","level":"WARN","message":"[RequestedSecret [path='database/creds/my-role', mode=RENEW]] Lease  │
│ [leaseId='database/creds/my-role/ej2iuCzhcO8gToGjX3mFeOgg', leaseDuration=PT5M, renewable=true] Status 403 Forbidden: 1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n; nested exception is o │
│ rg.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: \"{\"errors\":[\"1 error occurred:\\n\\t* permission denied\\n\\n\"]}<EOL>\"","thread":"main","process_id":"8","logger":"org.s │
│ pringframework.vault.core.lease.SecretLeaseEventPublisher$LoggingErrorListener","class":"org.springframework.boot.logging.DeferredLog","method":"logTo"}
```

If, however, I change the **path to "*" and grant all capabilities it works just fine**.I'd really like to reduce the capabilities for the service to the specific db path.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This Vault error is thrown when Spring is attempting to read the secret at that path? Can you confirm the role for Spring when authenticating is indeed `my-role` as when you wrote to the Vault config for the secrets engine? Is the username in the database also named `my-role`?

Comment: @Micha, any fix for that issue ?